# External file does not load in jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am closely following the example of using jQuery tabs from here:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Specifically the ajax example. I have a page called **index.htm** with this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-themes/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
<li><a href="content1.html">Page Four</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi<p>
 sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus.<p> 
 Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor<p>

<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi 
neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent 
per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu 
risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
<p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. 
Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel 
pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed 
nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula 
velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus 
hendrerit hendrerit.</p>

 </div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis 
scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa 
ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi 
adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. 
Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod 
felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi 
neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent 
per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu 
risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
<p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. 
Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel 
pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed 
nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula 
velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus 
hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

From the example there I downloaded the file **content1.html** and placed it in the same folder as **index.htm**

It looks like this:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body><p>
<strong>This content was loaded via ajax.</strong></p>
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.
Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum
 quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus
lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna
quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae
 ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede
 varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum.
Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p></body></html>
```

However, when I click on tab 4, it shows nothing. Note I do the same as the example there: I have a fourth "li" element with no corresponding div.

(I am testing this on the file system. There are no spaces in the path..)

What is wrong?

[Edit]: Jai's comment is correct. This does not work on the file system, but it does work fine via a web server.

Is there anyway to load a file into the tab content without a webserver, (this is to be deployed to the file system)?

Comment: `href` are based on `id`(in this example) and you are putting a whole file in it. Create a tab with an id and load the data in the container.

Comment: _I am testing this on the file system._....don't!! ajax needs to be checked on server like localhost.

Comment: Check your network tab in the browser console and see the request sent when load the [Page four] tab.

Comment: @GuyT: Is this something that can be done on filesystem i.e. without webserver?

Comment: Probably it will work, but it's not a good practice. You will have CORS problems. It also won't work on every browser(Chrome will fail). Just use a server(Apache) or use a package like *AMPP.

Comment: I just tested this locally with brackets live preview in chrome and it's working fine... then I recalled the fact that brackets runs a server..!